# How can an AppCompatActivity communicate with FragmentActivity using the EventBus?

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

**Question**, How can an AppCompatActivity communicate with FragmentActivity using the EventBus?

**Findings**, FragmentActivity can communicate with AppCompatActivity and the onEvent method is called, but if we switch the communication path to AppCompatActivity communicates with FragmentActivity, the onEvent method is never called.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 private String data;
 @Override protected void onCreate{
  data = "private String data from MainActivity";
  EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(data);
 }
}

public class AccountFade extends FragmentActivity{
 private String mAccountFadeData;
 @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
 public void onEvent(String s){
  Toast.makeText(this, "private String mAccountFadeData from MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  this.mAccountFadeData = s;
 }

 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override public void onDestroy(){
  EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
  super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create class that contain one String variable and fire that class by EventBus.

So first create class like this

```
public class DataChangeEvent {
    private String data;

    public DataChangeEvent(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Now use this for your event

Post in Activtiy :

```
 EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new DataChangeEvent(data));
```

Get in FragmentActivity :

```
 @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
 public void onEvent(DataChangeEvent event){
      Toast.makeText(this, "private String mAccountFadeData from MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      this.mAccountFadeData = event.getData();
 }
```

Comment: please, correct me if i'm wrong, i can not pass my class member variable "data" from MainActivity (EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(data);)? I saw that after I made a class for representing the string (new DataChangeEvent(data)) your example worked like a charm.